# How to get TFS collection from caught WorkItemChangedEvent?

Tags: tfs

I've written a TFS plug-in that catches the WorkItemChangedEvent but I can't see how to get to which collection this event applies? any clues? I can see "DisplayUrl" that tells me the host the TPC's on but not the TPC itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you can get it from: requestContext.ServiceHost.Name from the handler

```
public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext
```